# Retrieving a data export from an iOS Application

Tags: android, ios, iphone, export, itunes

Currently working on an application that I need to have the ability to export a bunch of 'logs'. Logs would be a combination of a number of different bits of information, which would total approximately 30 columns.

Preferably this export would be in 'tab separated' file format, but I am trying to find out how I would download it from an iOS device.

Android, as I understand isn't very difficult as it would just be saved to an accessible location on the phone. iOS on the other hand would need to be retrieved somehow through an iTunes sync. Is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save those Logs in application sandbox, either within Document or Cache directory. You can implement an email functionality to send the logs to a server but if you are interested only giving access of logs to developer then yes you can download it from **Organizer** window. Follow the below steps..

1. Connect your device and open the **Organizer** window.
2. Corresponding to your device name, click on the **Applications** options.
3. Download the contents of your application and open it. This will give you the app sandbox structure from where you can extract the logs where you have saved.